# How to split a column by using length split and MaxSplit in Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

For Example

If I have a Column as given below by calling and showing the CSV in Pyspark

```
+--------+
|   Names|
+--------+
|Rahul   |
|Ravi    |
|Raghu   |
|Romeo   |
+--------+
```

if I specify in my functions as Such

Length = 2
Maxsplit = 3

Then I have to get the results as

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
|Col_1     |Col_2      |Col_3     |
+----------+-----------+----------+
|      Ra  |      hu   |    l     |
|      Ra  |      vi   |    Null  |
|      Ra  |      gh   |    u     |
|      Ro  |      me   |    o     |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Simirarly in Pyspark

Length = 3
Max split = 2      it should provide me the output such as

```
+----------+-----------+
|Col_1     |Col_2      |
+----------+-----------+
|      Rah |      ul   |
|      Rav |      i    |
|      Rag |      hu   |
|      Rom |      eo   |
+----------+-----------+
```

This is how it should look like, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to go about this. Should be faster than any looping or udf solution.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def split(df,length,maxsplit):
    return df.withColumn('Names',F.split("Names","(?<=\\G{})".format('.'*length)))\
               .select(*((F.col("Names")[x]).alias("Col_"+str(x+1)) for x in range(0,maxsplit)))
  
split(df,3,2).show()

#+-----+-----+
#|Col_1|Col_2|
#+-----+-----+
#|  Rah|   ul|
#|  Rav|    i|
#|  Rag|   hu|
#|  Rom|   eo|
#+-----+-----+

split(df,2,3).show()

#+-----+-----+-----+
#|col_1|col_2|col_3|
#+-----+-----+-----+
#|   Ra|   hu|    l|
#|   Ra|   vi|     |
#|   Ra|   gh|    u|
#|   Ro|   me|    o|
#+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Absolutely marvelous, Exactly as expected murtihash, Your logic is perfect

Comment: Thanks a lot, murtihash

Comment: Glad to help , the empty cell in the output will be an empty string like `'' ` so if u want Null instead of that just attach `.replace('',None)` at the end

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("Raghu",1),("Ravi",2),("Rahul",3)],schema=["Name","val"])
def fn (split,max_n,tst):
    for i in range(max_n):
        tst_loop=tst.withColumn("coln"+str(i),F.substring(F.col("Name"),(i*split)+1,split))
        tst=tst_loop
    return(tst)
tst_res = fn(3,2,tst)
```

The for loop can also replaced by a list comprehension or reduce, but i felt in you case,  a for loop looked neater. they have the same physical plan anyway.

The results

```
+-----+---+-----+-----+
| Name|val|coln0|coln1|
+-----+---+-----+-----+
|Raghu|  1|  Rag|   hu|
| Ravi|  2|  Rav|    i|
|Rahul|  3|  Rah|   ul|
+-----+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Raghu was helpful

Comment: Beautifully Written Raghu, I Really appreciate your effort and logic

Comment: Happy to hear. Can you also upvote the answer, which is the common community practice

Comment: Sure Raghu, Your Code definitely deserves an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def split(data,length,maxSplit):
    start=1
    for i in range(0,maxSplit):
        data = data.withColumn(f'col_{start}-{start+length-1}',f.substring('channel',start,length))
        start=length+1
    return data

df = split(data,3,2)        
df.show()
+--------+----+-------+-------+
| channel|type|col_1-3|col_4-6|
+--------+----+-------+-------+
|     web|   0|    web|       |
|     web|   1|    web|       |
|     web|   2|    web|       |
| twitter|   0|    twi|    tte|
| twitter|   1|    twi|    tte|
|facebook|   0|    fac|    ebo|
|facebook|   1|    fac|    ebo|
|facebook|   2|    fac|    ebo|
+--------+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shubham Jain was helpful

Comment: I Really appreciate the Code what you have written Shubham Jain, Beautifully written

Comment: It's The output that I had in my mind, and this is what I had expected, Good Logic Brother, Keep it up

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is useful-

### Load the test data

> Note: written in scala

```scala
  val Length = 2
    val Maxsplit = 3
    val df = Seq("Rahul", "Ravi", "Raghu", "Romeo").toDF("Names")
    df.show(false)
    /**
      * +-----+
      * |Names|
      * +-----+
      * |Rahul|
      * |Ravi |
      * |Raghu|
      * |Romeo|
      * +-----+
      */
```

### split the string col as per the length and offset

```scala
    val schema = StructType(Range(1, Maxsplit + 1).map(f => StructField(s"Col_$f", StringType)))
    val split = udf((str:String, length: Int, maxSplit: Int) =>{
      val splits = str.toCharArray.grouped(length).map(_.mkString).toArray
      RowFactory.create(splits ++ Array.fill(maxSplit-splits.length)(null): _*)
    }, schema)

    val p = df
     .withColumn("x", split($"Names", lit(Length), lit(Maxsplit)))
     .selectExpr("x.*")

    p.show(false)
    p.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----+-----+-----+
      * |Col_1|Col_2|Col_3|
      * +-----+-----+-----+
      * |Ra   |hu   |l    |
      * |Ra   |vi   |null |
      * |Ra   |gh   |u    |
      * |Ro   |me   |o    |
      * +-----+-----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Col_1: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Col_2: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Col_3: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### `Dataset[Row]` -> `Dataset[Array[String]]`

```scala
 val x = df.map(r => {
      val splits = r.getString(0).toCharArray.grouped(Length).map(_.mkString).toArray
      splits ++ Array.fill(Maxsplit-splits.length)(null)
    })
    x.show(false)
    x.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-----------+
      * |value      |
      * +-----------+
      * |[Ra, hu, l]|
      * |[Ra, vi,]  |
      * |[Ra, gh, u]|
      * |[Ro, me, o]|
      * +-----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- value: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      */
```

Comment: The Code is really Well Written Someshwar Kale, I traced the code which you have written Works really well, But basically I needed the Code to be written in absolute Pyspark, But Scala is also fine could understand there no much changes between the two.

Comment: I Really appreciate your Work Someshwar Kale